# Selenium - Get href from parent element after searching for child

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors

Some of the attribute values on this page, like the href and id values, are generated by a script with a identifying value tagged on.  In order to generate the value of an element id tag to click it, I need the identifier for the item it references.  This is a list of items and I can only delineate them by the text name in the  element.  I need to then go up to the  parent where the href element has the id value listed.  The html looks like this:

```
<a class="item" href="#/subscription/90cefc7a42c2c3240142d973496d1287">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-2 item-list-image text-left">
        <stuff>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-lg-4">
        <h4>
            <strong class="ng-binding">Smoke Sequential</strong>
        </h4>
        <i class="icon-monitor"></i>
        <span class="ng-scope" translate-values="{"status":"Active"}" translate="subscription.currentStatus">Active Subscription</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 visible-lg">
        <stuff>
    </div>
</a>
```

I think the solution is a findElement(By.XPath(something)) or maybe a cssSelector but I don't know either to save my soul.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't quite get what you want to extract and what you have as input data for the example HTML you posted. Can you explain what you'd like to get from the sample?

Answer (score 0):

XPath is the only locator strategy to has a concept of a *parent*.

Therefore you are stuck with it. Below is C# code to get the parent of a given element (you've not specified what language you *are* using):

```
 IWebElement parent = element.FindElement(By.XPath(".."));
```

This is down to the fact that `..` in XPath means the direct parent.